# PHP - Split street name and street address

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to strip street numbers from street name. I face the problem when there is no numerical part like `Avenue ABC` or when street name starts with number like `10. Street 46`.

My regex right now is:

```
([^\d]+)\s?(.+)
```

These are test strings:

```
St. Stephen 12
Avenue ABC
Avenue AB
10. Street 46
```

Result should looks like:

```
array = (0 => 'St. Stephen', 1 => '12')
array = (0 => 'Avenue', 1 => 'ABC')
array = (0 => 'Avenue', 1 => 'AB')
array = (0 => '10. Street', 1 => '46')
```

**Live regex: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cil**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the below regex which produces two captures of one contains all the chars upot the last space where another group contain last word.

```
^(.+)\s(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cin)